# A circular reference was detected Linq

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

getting this error below 
trying to have relation that says 1 post can have multiple postComments

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[DAO.Models.PostComment, DAO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

```
int userId = (int)Session["UserId"];
try
{
    IEnumerable<Post> userPosts;
    userPosts = (from q in db.Posts
                    where q.UserId == userId
                    && q.PostId > postid
                    select q).Take(5).ToList();


    return Json(userPosts.Select(x => new
    {
        success = 1,
        contenttext = x.PostContent,
        postId = x.PostId,
        comments = x.PostComments
    }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Json(new { success = 0 });

}
finally
{
    //db.Dispose();
}
```

**My Post class**

```
public partial class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        this.PostComments = new List<PostComment>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }

    public partial class PostComment
    {
        public long PostCommentID { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int ParentCommentID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Post` class, you reference to PostComment and in your `PostComment` class you reference to your `Post` again, this is where the circular referencing happened, you can either use Json.NET http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx and do the below

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Formatting.Indented, 
                            new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                                   ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
                            })
```

To ignore reference loop handling, or alternatively, cast it to an anonymous class before serialising it.

Comment: do you have a snippet for  cast it to an anonymous class before serialising it.

Comment: var y = from p in db.Posts select new { PostID = p.PostID, Comments = p.Comments}

Comment: @cherhan where i can put it to reuse in all my application?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have some constraints in your database about certain columns that *must* reference a valid *row* in some table, and there is a circular reference here. It has to update the rows in the order they depend on each other, but due to the circular reference this is not possible. There is no single row that can be updated first that will satisfy the database constraints at that point.